# How to let Songbird know that its watched folder is moved?

Tags: songbird

Recently I've moded my Songbird's watch folder to a new location and naturally Songbird now don't link it's library files to physical files. Is there any way I can relink those files to new location so that Songbird can play them from new location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik it's still not supported.

However, you could try the following:

In `Tools / Options / Manage Files` enable `Allow Songbird to manage files` and select your desired destination.

It will **not** move the files but **copy over your whole library** with the given naming convention.

So, before you try this, make sure to understand it's implications.

I have not used it from the start but doing it now. That way all my newly imported media automatically moves to that folder. It's **not the watched folder** feature though.

Comment: thanks for the answer but this is not what i want.

Comment: @Donotalo: yes I figured, what you asked for is not support with SB currently.